# Deep merge two objects(nested ) in JavaScript using key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
{
"cards": [
{

  "iid": 154423,
  "number": 1,
  "name": "name",
  "sub_arr": [
    {

      "name": "name",
      "id": "94184",
      "point": "6",
      "event": "cff",
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "id": "90363",
      "event": "cff",
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "id": "94185",
      "point": "3",
      "event": "cff",
    },
    ],
  "support": [
    {
      "name": "Richardson",
      "id": "43478",
    },
    {
      "name": "Jason",
      "id": "43582",
    },
    .
    .
    .
   ]
},
{

  "iid": 154430,
  "number": 2,
  "sub_arr": [
    {
      "name": "name",
      "id": "94174",
      "point": "6",
      "event": "cff",
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "id": "90373",
      "event": "cff",
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "id": "94175",
      "point": "3",
      "event": "cff",
    },
    ],
  "support": [
    {
      "name": "son",
      "id": "43468",
    },
    {
      "name": "Jas",
      "id": "43552",
    },
   ]
}
],

"status_text": "success",

"status_code": 200

}
```

To update that initial data i receive updated key value pairs in below format

```
"cards": [
{

  "iid": 154423,
  "number": 1,
  "name": "name",
  "sub_arr": [
    {

      "name": "name",
      "id": "94184",
      "point": "6",
      "event": "ghd",
    },
],
  "support": [
    {
      "name": "dson",
      "id": "43478",
    },
}
]
```

Now i deep merge these two object, and i don't any duplicate entry merging should be based on the id of each sub array object, I have tried with 'lodash' but it didn't worked, I am getting duplicate values. So i am looking for a way where I can merge these by comparing the Ids of the sub arrays

Comment: *"It didn't worked"*: without your code we cannot see what you did wrong.

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you use a tag. The JSON tag contains: _"Do not use this tag for native JavaScript objects or JavaScript object literals. Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."_ Both snippets don't contain valid JSON. I assume, these are JavaScript literals. Don't use the JSON tag for JavaScript literals. You should also remove invalid code like `...` and post a [mcve] instead. Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform for specific questions. What is your specific question?

Answer (score 1):

Given the two objects below function will merge two objects from its keys.
Refer to the code below :

```js
const object1 = {
  "cards": [
    {
      "iid": 154423,
      "number": 1,
      "name": "name",
      "sub_arr": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "94184",
          "point": "6",
          "event": "cff",
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "90363",
          "event": "cff",
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "94185",
          "point": "3",
          "event": "cff",
        },
      ],
      "support": [
        {
          "name": "Richardson",
          "id": "43478",
        },
        {
          "name": "Jason",
          "id": "43582",
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "iid": 154430,
      "number": 2,
      "sub_arr": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "94174",
          "point": "6",
          "event": "cff",
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "90373",
          "event": "cff",
        },
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "94175",
          "point": "3",
          "event": "cff",
        },
      ],
      "support": [
        {
          "name": "son",
          "id": "43468",
        },
        {
          "name": "Jas",
          "id": "43552",
        },
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status_text": "success",
  "status_code": 200
};

const object2 = {
  "cards": [
    {
      "iid": 154423,
      "number": 1,
      "name": "name",
      "sub_arr": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "id": "94184",
          "point": "6",
          "event": "ghd",
        },
      ],
      "support": [
        {
          "name": "dson",
          "id": "43478",
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
};



function deepMerge(obj1, obj2) {
  for (let key in obj2) {
    if (obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof obj1[key] === 'object' && typeof obj2[key] === 'object') {
        deepMerge(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
      } else {
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
      }
    }
  }
}



deepMerge(object1, object2);

console.log(object1);
```